# AFNetworking: Issue with multiple files upload

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, networking, afnetworking

I'm working on certain part of some app. That part is file upload manager.  I have implemented an UploadManager class, which is singleton that inherits from NSObject and has method:

```
- (void)addNewUploadWithFileData:(NSData *)fileData
               withThumbnailData:(NSData *)thumbnailData
                      withUserId:(int32_t)userId
                        withType:(UploadType)uploadType
                   withMediaType:(MediaType)mediaType
                    withDelegate:(id<UploadDelegate>)delegate;
```

This method creates new upload object. Upload object is one of subclasses of BasicUpload class which inherits from AFHTTPClient.

The purpose of all this implementation to allow multiple files upload, control of them and other features.

In a scenario when I'm adding to upload multiple times the same file, all is working perfectly, all the uploads are uploading simultaneously.
But in a scenario, when I'm adding some file to upload, and then adding some other smaller file to upload, this smaller file is uploaded and other are not.

I have inspected, what is going on, and found that when I'm adding new other file to upload, then new request is created (obviously), after it has been created, all other upload objects that were added before are released(deallocated).
It happens in AFHTTPClient.m, in method:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)multipartFormRequestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                                   path:(NSString *)path
                                             parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                              constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData))block
```

when it reaches the part:

```
__block AFMultipartFormData *formData = [[[AFMultipartFormData alloc] initWithURLRequest:request stringEncoding:self.stringEncoding] autorelease];
```

after that all the previous upload objects (which are subclasses of AFHTTPClient) are deallocated.

What am I doing wrong??? Or is there probably some bug???

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider adding all your AFRequestOperations to a [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) so they'll be retained?

Comment: The upload manager singleton has property NSOperationQueue. All new upload object on it's creation is adding his operation to that operation queue.

Comment: Did you try setting `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1 just for testing purposes ? My guess is you're on some weird kind of a operation deadlock.

Comment: I have tried now. Same story. I think that problem is not in operation object. Because it happens immediately after new AFHTTPClient object is created(after __block AFMultipartFormData *formData = [[[AFMultipartFormData alloc] initWithURLRequest:request stringEncoding:self.stringEncoding] autorelease];), before new the new operation object is created.

Comment: Wait, why are you recreating the client ... ? You just need to create a new AFRequestOperation, not a new client every time.

Comment: Because of some considerations, I need each time new AFHTTPClient.

Comment: Would you mind sharing those considerations ... ? It doesn't make much sense. One client should address all of the uploads, Otherwise the fact you have a Singleton Client doesn't matter at all

Comment: It happens after __block AFMultipartFormData *formData = [[[AFMultipartFormData alloc] initWithURLRequest:request stringEncoding:self.stringEncoding] autorelease] is applied

Comment: The consideration are: some of upload object will be uploaded in chunks, for each chunk, new request is created. So one of upload objects is single request, and the other is multi requested, when it gets response, it creates new request. I know that this is stuped, but that is the requirement that I need to implement.

Comment: I don't think that's stupid, but it does sound like something that could be achieved with a single AFHTTPClient.